# Lists, insertion and visualization with main managment menu

Tags: list, visualization, insertion, bidirectional

I have to insert some words in a list, and than visualize them.
Simple, it works for now.
The problems come when i add this function that i call "menu managment"

```
main()//MENU MANAGMENT
{
    list_creation(&p0);
do
{
    system("cls");
    printf("\t- MENU -\n");
    printf("Press 1 to insert a word!\n");
    printf("Press 2 to visualize.\n");
    printf("Premi S to exit... \n ");

    scanf("%c", &sc);


    if(sc=='2') {visualize(p0);system("pause");}
    if(sc=='1') {p0=insertion(p0);}


}
    while(sc!='s');


}
```

When i try to do the word insertion it show like there was a system cls, the first procedure don't run, and it don't let me insert any words, and then when i try to visualize the list, it shows me some empty elements (like he did only the malloc), as many as i clicked the "1" button on my keyboard.

This is all the code (it was in italian but i translated it)

```
/*           -BIDREZIONALI-
Inserimento in testa di una parola --> word insertion on the top of the list
Inserimento in coda --> word insertion in the last element of the list
cancellazoine in coda --> cancel the last element of the list 
cancellazione in testa --> cancel the first element if the list
stampa delle parole dalla prima all'ultima e viceversa --> print all the words */ 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

// DICHIARAZIONE

struct elemento {
      char info [20];
      struct elemento *suc;//points to the next node
      struct elemento *prev;//PUNTA to the previous node
};

      struct elemento *p0;
      char word [20], sc;


void list_creation(struct elemento **p0)
{
     *p0=NULL;//empty list
}

struct elemento *insertion(struct elemento *p0)
{
     struct elemento *p;

     printf("insert a word:\t");
     gets(word);
     p=(struct elemento*)malloc(sizeof(struct elemento));
     strcpy(p->info,word);
     if(p0==NULL)
 {
             p0=p;
             p->prev=NULL;
             p->next=NULL;
 }
 else{
             p0->prev=p;
             p->next=p0;
             p->prev=NULL;
             p0=p;
      }
      return p0;
 }


void VisualizzaLista(struct elemento *p0)
{

       if(p0==NULL){printf("empty list");}
   else{
        printf("lista -> ");

        // while it's not empty
    while(p0 != NULL)
    {
        printf("[%s]", p0->info); // information visualization
        printf(" -> ");
        p0 = p0->suc; // slide of one node
    }
    }
   printf("NULL\n");

}



main()//MENU MANAGMENT
{
    list_creation(&p0);
do
{
    system("cls");
    printf("\t- MENU -\n");
    printf("Press 1 to insert a word!\n");
    printf("Press 2 to visualize.\n");
    printf("Premi S to exit... \n ");

    scanf("%c", &sc);


    if(sc=='2') {visualize(p0);system("pause");}
    if(sc=='1') {p0=insertion(p0);}


}
    while(sc!='s');


}
```

thanks.